# Ionic 2 push isn't working correctly for some reason

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have a problem, i think it's simple enough but i can manage to figure it out by myself, im having a push and im sure i am getting new data from the navParams, i checked it, but it doesn't get into the next position of the array, it gets in the first position. I really have no idea what's going on,and i am getting a little crazy.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {CadenasmercadosPage} from "../cadenasmercados/cadenasmercados";
import {ListaTerminadaPage} from "../lista-terminada/lista-terminada";
import {Sucursal} from "../../Data/sucursal.interface";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
  cadenasMercadosPage=CadenasmercadosPage;
  Listas: Sucursal[]=[];
  DatosLista: Sucursal;
  Vacio= false;
  listaTerminada = ListaTerminadaPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.DatosLista = this.navParams.data;
    this.Listas.push(this.DatosLista);
    if (this.Listas[0].listaNombre){
      this.Vacio = false;
    } else {
      this.Vacio = true;
    }
  }

}
```

The issue is on the OnInit method, at least that's my guess... you can ignore the if.

Home html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar
    color="danger"
    hideBackButton>
    <ion-title>
      Listas
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-list [hidden]="Vacio">
    <button ion-item
            *ngFor="let lista of Listas"
            [navPush]="listaTerminada"
            [navParams]="lista"
            >{{lista.listaNombre}}</button>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-fab bottom right>
    <button  ion-fab mini
             color="danger"
             [navPush]="cadenasMercadosPage">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: "but it doesn't get into the next position of the array, it gets in the first position" can you elaborate more ?

Comment: wait, shouldn't it be this.Listas = this.DatosLista; instead of this.Listas.push(this.DatosLista);?

Comment: @CharlieNg everytime i get new data into the array it goest to Lista[0], i push more stuff into the array, but new info gets into 0 index

Comment: It seems the old values didn't get stored in the array, and you are only getting new date one time on ngOnInit. can I see your home.html?

Comment: @CharlieNg Done

Comment: how did you get new data? by refreshing the page? ngOnInit will only be called once, and you are pushing the new data once, so it is always the 0 index one....

Comment: @CharlieNg when i navigate back to Home, with  NavParams

Comment: so where did you get the new data from? Do you have a http call everytime you navigate back to Home?

Comment: From another page in my project @CharlieNg

Comment: ok, that sounds like you need to have a service to share the data between components/pages. Define your Listas variable in the service and when you get the data from another page, push it there. When you come back to this home page, you will have the data available

Comment: or you can use nav parameter. Will try to upload an example later.